# .NET Compact application throws TypeLoadException when not run through debugger

Tags: compact-framework, windows-ce, typeloadexception

If I run my .NET Compact application using ConmanClient, everything works. But if I try running my application by executing it directly from the shell, it throws TypeLoadException (a window appears displaying this without any additional information). I use .NET Compact 3.5 and Windows CE 6.0 R2.

Comment: Does "Start without debugging" (Ctrl-F5) correctly launch the app?

Comment: I don't know what happened, but when I recompiled the project and surrounding libraries, everything works.